# How to swap data from two columns in grid view by using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

How to swap data from two columns in grid view by using vb.net?(swap can be done with upr column data or downcolumn data mean swap must be possible with both the rows i,e if we are have row 1.row2 ,row 3, now if we wants to swap in any 2 rows it must be done because in middle row2 we are using both button up and down if we want to swap data with upper row by click up button it will swap and vice-versa in down button)

Comment: What have you tried? We would be glad to help if you can show us you have helped yourself.

Comment: actually i have a grid in which i wants to on click of a button it will swap the data of two column and it will swap with both upper column and well as down  column but one at a time .. for that i will use 2 button one for upper and second for lower button so that both can fire

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried?

Comment: i m not yet do anything i need any example then with the help of example i will try my self.. so if u have  any idea or example do tell me